# button.onclick() causes "Unfortunately xxx has stopped working

Tags: android

Newbie to Android. Trying to make simple SMS text messenger(for higher purpose) based on example from Web. Code below. Phone is S4 mini (API19). 
System works(text msg properly sent) when "sendSMSmessage()" is called as part of onCreate. As soon as I try to set the onClick interrupt - the code response (on the phone) "Unfortunately xxx has stopped working". Tried extend activity and AppCompatActivity (as indicated with comments). Missing some kind of setup / reference for the onClick method call? Thanks for your help.

```
package com.example.tas_pb_usr1.ArtSafe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

//public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//    Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
     Button sendBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       kkBtnSetup();
          sendSMSMessage();
}
    protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
/*        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();*/

        String phoneNo = "1234567";
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().toString();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        String message = "Some SMS text   " +  formattedDate;

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void kkBtnSetup(){
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Here is layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send SMS"
        android:id="@+id/Sms_send_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post your log stack

Comment: please paste the logcat messages you receive when the app crashes. It will be helpful for you and us to know which part of the code is causing the crash.

Comment: have you added the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> in your manifest?

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: just initialize your button property in oncreate()

Comment: @TAS_StackOverflow : Please check my below answer.I hope it will works

Answer (score 1):

Please use this way,if you use this logic then no need to add button onclickListner and  `kkBtnSetup()` .

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/Sms_send_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Send SMS"
 android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
 android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
 android:onClick="sendSMSMessage"/>
```

Using the attribute android: onClick we declare the method name that has to be present on the parent activity.

```
    public void sendSMSMessage(View v)
        {
        String phoneNo = "1234567";
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().toString();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        String message = "Some SMS text   " +  formattedDate;

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please add the line in onCreate method.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button sendBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
       kkBtnSetup();
          sendSMSMessage();
}
 protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
/*        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();*/

        String phoneNo = "1234567";
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().toString();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        String message = "Some SMS text   " +  formattedDate;

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void kkBtnSetup(){
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send button is not defined and it is null, so you should become a NullPointerException. Add this line

```
Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
```

into your onCreate method before the call of the kkBtnSetup() method

So your onCreate method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
    kkBtnSetup();
    sendSMSMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your button before setting click listener on it. Like this.

```
Button sendBtn;
```

You should use

```
sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
```

inside `onCreate()` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
    kkBtnSetup();
    sendSMSMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize the send button by using

```
sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
```

after this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you must initialize button before using it, in your function `kkBtnSetup()`

```
sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sms_send_button);
```